# C++: How to create small speed tests for templated classes?

Tags: c++, templates, testing, boost, dictionary

First I'll show what I camed up with and I want to know how if you think that my solution is risky, bad and incompedent. We have a normal std map. We want to make it safe for multythreaded read/write operations. And test its speed. With boost we have 2 options use - `mutable boost::mutex` or `boost::shared_mutex`. So this is what I camed up with...

I created a [test interface data structure](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/branches/v0.5/ConcurrentMaps/src/test_data_structure.h?r=1497), , [map with scoped_locks](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/branches/v0.5/ConcurrentMaps/src/general_map_data_structure.h?r=1497), [map with shared_locks](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/branches/v0.5/ConcurrentMaps/src/general_map_data_structure_shared_locks.h?r=1497). Now came intresting part - how to test tham with minimall code amounts?

I have created a test case:

```
    template< typename  t1, typename  t2>
    void test(t1 k1, t2 v1)
    {
            map_t_1 k = boost::lexical_cast<map_t_1>(k1);
            map_t_2 v = boost::lexical_cast<map_t_2>(v1);

            Ds.put(k, v);
            if (Ds.containsKey(k))
            {
                    Ds.get(k);
                    Ds.get(k);
                    Ds.get(k);
            }
            Ds.remove(k);
    }
```

and tests: (this is most incompedent part IMHO)

```
    void test_int( int i)
    {
            boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock_r(results);
            boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(tests);
            test<int, int>(i, i);
    }

    void test_string( std::string s)
    {
            s += "abcdefghigklmnop";
            std::string r = "abcdefghigklmnop" + s;

            boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock_r(results);
            boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(tests);
            test<std::string, std::string>(s, r);
    }
```

And I let programmer that creates a tet to chouse to use a string or int test:

```
    //code inside tester class
    void submit_test( int test_number )
    {
            if (test_type == "int")
            {
                    io_service.post(boost::bind(&test_map_wraper_pooled<map_wraper_t, map_t_1, map_t_2>::test_int, this, test_number));
            }
            else if (test_type == "string")
            {
                    io_service.post(boost::bind(&test_map_wraper_pooled<map_wraper_t, map_t_1, map_t_2>::test_string, this, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(test_number)));
            }
    }

// code programer can write to test my map on ints
test_map_wraper_pooled<general_map_data_structure<int, int>, int, int > GeneralMapTest(tasks_n);
GeneralMapTest.start_tests("int");
//or on strings
test_map_wraper_pooled<general_map_data_structure<std::string, std::string>, std::string, std::string > GeneralMapTest(tasks_n);
GeneralMapTest.start_tests("string");
```

Here is my [tester](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/branches/v0.5/ConcurrentMaps/src/test_map_wraper_with_asio_based_thread_pool.h?r=1497) class, and [main](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/branches/v0.5/ConcurrentMaps/src/main.cpp?r=1497) app example.

So it was what I camed up with for quick and dirty typed class testing. What do you think - is it possible to create small testing suite with out dinamic typesw casting inside tester code for it all to compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to measure performance of the two different implementations, you should probably be using a test that mimics the expected behavior of the class under stress. That probably involves quite a lot more operations than the `put`, `contains`, `get; get; get;`, `remove`, and probably run for a while in a loop. Also I do not quite understand why the `lexical_cast` or why the tests are performing the locks, are the locks not handled inside the map?

Note that adding locking to a container does not make the container *thread-safe*, you need to adapt the interface, and it is not trivial to do so in an exception safe manner. You don't show the interfaces of your class and the use cases don't show them either (what is the type returned by `get`?) but you should be aware that no operation in the container should yield references or pointers into the container, as that will break thread safety.

Comment: As you can see for example  [here](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/branches/v0.5/ConcurrentMaps/src/general_map_data_structure.h?r=1497) I tend to test not a real std map but one boosted with locks. so locks are handled inside my class that is being tested. And that class is my adoption of map interface with locks. I compare it with andother boostd with locks class.

Comment: @Kiss: A few comments: It is interesting that you chose to use the `mutable` keyword for the mutex, but did not mark any method as `const`. I would use more sensible names than `map_t_1`. Your `get` method is modifying the map (adding keys that did not exist before), there is no point on returning the *key* in the `put` method, which might involve memory allocations (think `std::string`), none of your methods take the `key`/`value` by reference (again, potentially unneeded copies), `containsKey` is not *that* useful (does not guarantee that a later `get` will retrieve anything)...